# How can I write a file in res directory?

Tags: android, filewriter

I want to store a .json file within the res directory. How should the path be defined?

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("path_here");
```

Answer (score 3):

You **can't**! Resources are read-only at runtime.

Comment: Hm... Okey, thanks! Will be thinking for a different approach